# How to check multiple field of Django Object is exist after assignment?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating an article object like this for an old model that we currently use and I do not want to change the legacy model.

```py
Article.objects.create(
            category=NEWSFEED,
            date=self.parse_date(item),
            display_type=ARTICLE,
            name=self.article_name(item),
            image=self.generate_image(item),
)
```

These fields are depended on an **Item** and some items might not have this fields or there can be an issue while parsing Item so I want to make sure all the fields are created and assigned correctly.
Also I want to be informed if any field is empty.

I added **error as an Array Field**  to check every these fields in another method like this so later on I can check the error list and see what is wrong with this article.

```py
def check_article_fields(self, article):
    if not article.date:
        article.error.append('Date of this article is missing')
    if not article.name:
        article.error.append('Name of this article is missing')
    if not article.subtitle:
        article.error.append('Subtitle of this article is missing')
    if not article.html_template:
        article.error.append('Html of this article is missing')
    if not article.images:
        article.error.append('Images of this article is missing')
    if not article.content:
        article.error.append('Content of this article is missing')
```

**However this looks like really really ugly and it could be better, yet right now I can not think of any another solution.**

Comment: you can fetch an attribute in python using `getattr(article, attr)` which returns the value of the attribute, so you could loop through the field names, using this to check if it's `None` or not and then add the error all in one line.

Comment: Not sure you should save this in the model though, as it can be retrieved with a query directly. You can query your db directly for a list of articles that don't have a `name` like this: `Article.objects.filter(name='')` and those that don't have a date with `Article.objects.filter(date__isnull=True)`. You could add these filters to your admin list filters in the admin site so you can easily check them there (or have someone on your team who doesn't program check them there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned in a comment above that I wouldn't save the error into the model. First, because it's usually bad practice to save information that can be retrieved from other fields, as it can go out of sync. You can hook this into your `save()` or `pre_save()` methods, but there are ways to bypass them. Second, because you can query the db directly for articles with specific fields missing: `Article.objects.filter(date__isnull=True)` will return all articles with missing date.

Also, you can make all of this visible in the django admin site so that whoever is managing the site can check this easily. E.g. using [`list_filters`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).

But if you want to simplify your code, you can do this:

```
def check_article_fields(self, article):
    article.errors = article.errors or []
    article_fields = map(lambda x: x.name, article._meta.get_fields())
    for field_name in article_fields:
        if not getattr(article, field_name):
            article.errors.append(f"{field_name.title()} of this article is missing.")
```

Comment: Thank you @dirkgroten yes saving it in the model looks wrong when I think of it more deeply you are right also the simplification will do the job I believe thank you again!